React does not render the default files that are installed with Vite
I create a project with "npm create vite@latest", then create the Node packages with "npm install". I launch the local Vite server with "npm run dev", open in the browser "http://localhost:5173/", but the content of App.jsx (the example file that Vite creates when installed) does not render. index.html loads, but does not render the content of <div id="root"></div>.
In dev tools I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
I tried modifying vite.config.js, also clearing the browser cache and several other things.
